# How to bring data to Linux, currently it's on Windows machine.. (both Hyper-V guests)

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm learning my way through couple different things at a time. Linux(no GUI) is new to me, Hyper-V is new to me..

I have 2 VMs. One running Windows Server 2012(WVM), another running CentOS7(LVM).
I created additional virtual disk. Attached to WVM, powered up. In drive management I initialized this disk, created partition and copied some data to it.

Initially, I wanted to just attache same drive to LVM. Hyper-V wouldn't let me. It made me shut down both guests, then I was able to reattach.

Now, inside LVM I can see there is a disk by running `parted -l` Doing some research (but not trying it yet) - seems like I need to "attach" this storage in LVM, and then I can access files.

Then, if I want to connect this disk back - I need to shut down both guests and switch them up.

I don't really like this idea of shutting down VMs, but I do need some easy way to have shared storage in same Hyper-V environment.

How do I do it?

Comment: If both VM have network connectivity between each other why not simply create a shared folder on the windows side and mount it on linux? (or vice versa)

Comment: How can I mount network share on Linux? Or, how do I share folder in Linux?

Comment: Your best bet is to google "how to mount drive on CentOS" and there are lots of similar instruction.